# Azure Data Factory V2-Hosting the Integration Runtime

Tags: azure

We have an Azure VM where few SSIS packages run.
We are planning to get rid of the VM.
We are creating ADF instead of SSIS package.
We need to get data from on-premises sql server(which has only windows authentication) to Azure SQl server.
In ADF, created a self hosted Integration Runtime in my local machine and i am able to create linked services for both Azure sql server and on prem sql server.
So where should i host this Integration Runtime for this ADF to run ?
Can we get rid of the VM ?
IS there a way to have this Integration runtime somewhere else other than VM ?

Answer (score 0):

The self-hosted runtime needs to be hosted somewhere where it has access to your local resources, it can only run on a Windows machine, so you need some sort of machine, be it VM or physical.